# Is there an elegant way to extract individual words from variable names into an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

Basically I want to do this:

I get a string `"myVariableName"` and turn it into: `["my", "variable", "name"]`

I tried doing this using regex, but I get a lot of undefineds in my ending array it seems. The two possible cases for variable names are camel-case and upper snake-case in this situation.

```
const matchVariableNames =  /(\b[a-z]+)|([A-Z][a-z]+)|(\b[A-Z]+)|(_[A-Z]+)/g;
const variableName = 'myVariable';
let words = [];
let regexMatches;

while (regexMatches = matchVariableNames.exec(variableName)) {
  regexMatches.forEach((match) => {
    words.push(match);
  }); 
};
```

outputs:

```
["my", "my", undefined, undefined, undefined, "Variable", undefined, "Variable", undefined, undefined]
undefined
```

Comment: `"myVariableName".match(/((?:^|[A-Z])[a-z]+)/g)`  technically some non-alpha chars are acceptable as var names but this might suffice depending on your var naming convention

Comment: Or a better duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13720256/javascript-regex-camelcase-to-sentence

Comment: `console.log(
"myVariableName"
        .replace(/^[a-z]|[A-Z]/g, function(v, i) {
            return (i === 0 ? "":" ")+ v.toLowerCase();
        }).split(" ")
    ) `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a positive lookahead with uppercase letters. Then map only lower case letters.

```js
var string = 'myVariableName',
    array = string.split(/(?=[A-Z])/).map(a => a.toLowerCase());
    
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think a regular expression is a good fit for this. (I don't accept [Regular expression to identify CamelCased words with leading uppercase letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128305/regular-expression-to-identify-camelcased-words-with-leading-uppercase-letter) as a duplicate since the question does not ask for a regular expression persé).

The way I read it you want to parse words written in camelcase. Immediately I imagine special cases such as `"DOMElement` and `"PDFParser"`. I would expect the output to be `[ "DOM", "Element" ]` and `[ "PDF", "Parser" ]`. I think we can write a function that works like that.

```js
function parseWordsFromCamelCaseString(string) {
  var i, words, last_word_char, last_case, current_case;
  words = [];
  last_word_start = 0;
  last_case = null; // false=lower, true=upper

  for (i = 0; i < string.length; i += 1) {
    current_case = string[i].toUpperCase() === string[i];
    if (last_case !== null && current_case !== last_case) {
      if (current_case === true) { // lowercase to uppercase transition
        words.push(string.substring(last_word_start, i));
        last_word_start = i;
      } else { // uppercase to lowercase transition
        if (last_word_start < i - 1) {
          words.push(string.substring(last_word_start, i - 1));
        }
        last_word_start = i - 1;
      }
    }
    last_case = current_case;
  }
  if (last_word_start < i - 1) {
    words.push(string.substring(last_word_start, i));
  }
  return words;
}

console.log(parseWordsFromCamelCaseString("fooBar"));
console.log(parseWordsFromCamelCaseString("parseWordsFromCamelCaseString"));
console.log(parseWordsFromCamelCaseString("DOMElement"));
console.log(parseWordsFromCamelCaseString("fooDOMElement"));
```

Output

```
["foo", "Bar"]
["parse", "Words", "From", "Camel", "Case", "String"]
["DOM", "Element"]
["foo", "DOM", "Element"]
```

It also works for `"foo"` (no case transition) and `""` (empty string).

Comment: Do you recognise [javascript-regex-camelcase-to-sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13720256/javascript-regex-camelcase-to-sentence) as a duplicate then?

Comment: @mplungjan I don't see why. There are no non-regular expression answers. And none of them correctly handle the (not so-)special case that I outlined.

Answer (score -1):

I've created this:

```
x = 'myVariableName';
const isUpper = e => (e === e.toUpperCase());
[].reduce.call(x, (words, letter, i) => {
  if(isUpper(letter)) words.push([letter]);
  else {
    let length = words.length-1,
        word = words[length];
    words[length] = word+letter;
  }
  return words;
}, [[]]);
```

Returns `["my", "Variable", "Name"]`

Is it very elegant? We can fight about it, but I'm sure more than your RegExp. :P

Comment: It breaks on input like `"myPDFFile"`. It returns `[ "my", [ "p" ], [ "D" ], [ "F" ], "File" ]`