# capitalise and add space of ID when saving as pdf

Tags: javascript, capitalize

I have a savingasPDF function that I'm using which targets the id of what needs to be downloaded and saved as a pdf, it also then uses its id to create a title for the pdf. the id follow camel case so are 'writtenLikeThis'. I had added

```
 doc.text(15, 15, ID.replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1').trim().capitalize());
```

which was adding space and capitalising the first letter, so 'writtenLikeThis' would appear as 'Written Like This' as the title. However its suddenly stopped working, with the error of

> ID.replace(...).trim(...).capitalize is not a function

below is the complete function, I'm not sure why its no longer working but if anyone has any suggestions of how to rewrite the section that adds space and capitalizes i'd really appreciate the help.

```
    function saveAsPDF(ID) {
    let canvas = document.querySelector('#' + ID); 
    //creates image
    let canvasImg = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0); 
    //creates PDF from img
    let doc = new jsPDF('landscape'); 
    doc.setFontSize(12); 
    doc.text(15, 15, ID.replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1').trim().capitalize());  
    doc.addImage(canvasImg, 'PNG', 10, 20, 280, 150 ); 
    doc.save( ID +'.pdf');
}
```

to summarise I need camelCase to become Camel Case or Camel case.

**UPDATE**
solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13720440/14106443)
updated function below:

```
function saveAsPDF(ID) {
    let canvas = document.querySelector('#' + ID); 
    //creates image
    let canvasImg = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0); 
    //creates PDF from img
    let doc = new jsPDF('landscape'); 
    doc.setFontSize(12); 
    doc.text(15, 15, ID.replace(/^[a-z]|[A-Z]/g, function(v, i) {
    return i === 0 ? v.toUpperCase() : " " + v.toLowerCase()})); 
    doc.addImage(canvasImg, 'PNG', 10, 20, 280, 150 ); 
    doc.save( ID +'.pdf');
}
```

Comment: Is captialize an exsiting function ? I think you are looking for `toUpperCase()`

Comment: hi, `toUpperCase()` causes for the entire string to become uppercase, i just need  the first letter of each word to be upper case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make the first letter of a string uppercase in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/how-do-i-make-the-first-letter-of-a-string-uppercase-in-javascript)

Comment: i will try these solutions out and update on which worked, thank you !

Comment: found a working solution here [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/13720440/14106443)

Comment: Working solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13720440/14106443)